# What is the purpose of html that goes within iframe tags?

Tags: html

I read once somewhere that it was fallback content but it does not display when src fails to load.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body >
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/">
        <p>text</p>
    </iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A good resource to check for help with html and really most things web-related is developer.mozilla.org. In particular, they have a page on iframes that more or less mirrors @Quentin's answer.

Comment: Could you tell me which part of it says that?

Comment: There's a table pretty close to the top that says "Permitted Content: None"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [current specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element) the content model of an iframe is defined as "Nothing" so it is an error.

The [previous specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5) (from the '90s) said:

> The contents of the IFRAME element, on the other hand, should only be displayed by user agents that do not support frames or are configured not to display frames.

So it was a fallback, but for browsers that don't support the element, not for when the URL fails to load.